# Weird Hotlinking protection via .HTACCESS

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I'm on wordpress, and i want to show a logo/image when somebody try to hotlinking my website's content on their website (images). Till here, nothing special.

Around the web, i found a website that does the same thing, but has something different, something weird (i think), so:

If i put the link of any images hosted on my website, directly in the address bar, i see my logo of hotlinking protection.
While, if i put the link of any images hosted on this other website, directly in the address bar, i see the real image.

How can i do the same? How is this possible?

Searching on google i found a lot of example, and this is the code that i'm using for the .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?mywebsite.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp)$ https://www.dlapiper.com/~/media/Images/Insights/Publications/2015/warning.jpg [NC,R,L]
```

Is there a way to do this, as the other website?

Other thing, there is a way to show a logo for hotlinking hosted on my website? Thanks.

.HTACCES file:

```
# BEGIN W3TC Browser Cache
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
AddType text/css .css
AddType text/x-component .htc
AddType application/x-javascript .js
AddType application/javascript .js2
AddType text/javascript .js3
AddType text/x-js .js4
AddType text/html .html .htm
AddType text/richtext .rtf .rtx
AddType image/svg+xml .svg .svgz
AddType text/plain .txt
AddType text/xsd .xsd
AddType text/xsl .xsl
AddType text/xml .xml
AddType video/asf .asf .asx .wax .wmv .wmx
AddType video/avi .avi
AddType image/bmp .bmp
AddType application/java .class
AddType video/divx .divx
AddType application/msword .doc .docx
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
AddType application/x-msdownload .exe
AddType image/gif .gif
AddType application/x-gzip .gz .gzip
AddType image/x-icon .ico
AddType image/jpeg .jpg .jpeg .jpe
AddType application/json .json
AddType application/vnd.ms-access .mdb
AddType audio/midi .mid .midi
AddType video/quicktime .mov .qt
AddType audio/mpeg .mp3 .m4a
AddType video/mp4 .mp4 .m4v
AddType video/mpeg .mpeg .mpg .mpe
AddType application/vnd.ms-project .mpp
AddType application/x-font-otf .otf
AddType application/vnd.ms-opentype ._otf
AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.database .odb
AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart .odc
AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula .odf
AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics .odg
AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation .odp
AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet .ods
AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text .odt
AddType audio/ogg .ogg
AddType application/pdf .pdf
AddType image/png .png
AddType application/vnd.ms-powerpoint .pot .pps .ppt .pptx
AddType audio/x-realaudio .ra .ram
AddType application/x-shockwave-flash .swf
AddType application/x-tar .tar
AddType image/tiff .tif .tiff
AddType application/x-font-ttf .ttf .ttc
AddType application/vnd.ms-opentype ._ttf
AddType audio/wav .wav
AddType audio/wma .wma
AddType application/vnd.ms-write .wri
AddType application/font-woff .woff
AddType application/font-woff2 .woff2
AddType application/vnd.ms-excel .xla .xls .xlsx .xlt .xlw
AddType application/zip .zip
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType text/css A31536000
ExpiresByType text/x-component A31536000
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A31536000
ExpiresByType application/javascript A31536000
ExpiresByType text/javascript A31536000
ExpiresByType text/x-js A31536000
ExpiresByType text/html A3600
ExpiresByType text/richtext A3600
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml A3600
ExpiresByType text/plain A3600
ExpiresByType text/xsd A3600
ExpiresByType text/xsl A3600
ExpiresByType text/xml A3600
ExpiresByType video/asf A31536000
ExpiresByType video/avi A31536000
ExpiresByType image/bmp A31536000
ExpiresByType application/java A31536000
ExpiresByType video/divx A31536000
ExpiresByType application/msword A31536000
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject A31536000
ExpiresByType application/x-msdownload A31536000
ExpiresByType image/gif A31536000
ExpiresByType application/x-gzip A31536000
ExpiresByType image/x-icon A31536000
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A31536000
ExpiresByType application/json A31536000
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-access A31536000
ExpiresByType audio/midi A31536000
ExpiresByType video/quicktime A31536000
ExpiresByType audio/mpeg A31536000
ExpiresByType video/mp4 A31536000
ExpiresByType video/mpeg A31536000
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-project A31536000
ExpiresByType application/x-font-otf A31536000
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-opentype A31536000
ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.database A31536000
ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart A31536000
ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula A31536000
ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics A31536000
ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation A31536000
ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet A31536000
ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text A31536000
ExpiresByType audio/ogg A31536000
ExpiresByType application/pdf A31536000
ExpiresByType image/png A31536000
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-powerpoint A31536000
ExpiresByType audio/x-realaudio A31536000
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml A31536000
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash A31536000
ExpiresByType application/x-tar A31536000
ExpiresByType image/tiff A31536000
ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf A31536000
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-opentype A31536000
ExpiresByType audio/wav A31536000
ExpiresByType audio/wma A31536000
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-write A31536000
ExpiresByType application/font-woff A31536000
ExpiresByType application/font-woff2 A31536000
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-excel A31536000
ExpiresByType application/zip A31536000
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
</IfModule>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/x-component application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript text/x-js text/html text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/bmp application/java application/msword application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-msdownload image/x-icon application/json application/vnd.ms-access application/vnd.ms-project application/x-font-otf application/vnd.ms-opentype application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.database application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text audio/ogg application/pdf application/vnd.ms-powerpoint application/x-shockwave-flash image/tiff application/x-font-ttf application/vnd.ms-opentype audio/wav application/vnd.ms-write application/font-woff application/font-woff2 application/vnd.ms-excel
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    # DEFLATE by extension
    AddOutputFilter DEFLATE js css htm html xml
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
<FilesMatch "\.(css|htc|less|js|js2|js3|js4|CSS|HTC|LESS|JS|JS2|JS3|JS4)$">
FileETag MTime Size
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Pragma "public"
    Header append Cache-Control "public"
     Header set X-Powered-By "W3 Total Cache/0.9.5"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|rtf|rtx|svg|svgz|txt|xsd|xsl|xml|HTML|HTM|RTF|RTX|SVG|SVGZ|TXT|XSD|XSL|XML)$">
FileETag MTime Size
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Pragma "public"
    Header append Cache-Control "public"
     Header set X-Powered-By "W3 Total Cache/0.9.5"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(asf|asx|wax|wmv|wmx|avi|bmp|class|divx|doc|docx|eot|exe|gif|gz|gzip|ico|jpg|jpeg|jpe|json|mdb|mid|midi|mov|qt|mp3|m4a|mp4|m4v|mpeg|mpg|mpe|mpp|otf|_otf|odb|odc|odf|odg|odp|ods|odt|ogg|pdf|png|pot|pps|ppt|pptx|ra|ram|svg|svgz|swf|tar|tif|tiff|ttf|ttc|_ttf|wav|wma|wri|woff|woff2|xla|xls|xlsx|xlt|xlw|zip|ASF|ASX|WAX|WMV|WMX|AVI|BMP|CLASS|DIVX|DOC|DOCX|EOT|EXE|GIF|GZ|GZIP|ICO|JPG|JPEG|JPE|JSON|MDB|MID|MIDI|MOV|QT|MP3|M4A|MP4|M4V|MPEG|MPG|MPE|MPP|OTF|_OTF|ODB|ODC|ODF|ODG|ODP|ODS|ODT|OGG|PDF|PNG|POT|PPS|PPT|PPTX|RA|RAM|SVG|SVGZ|SWF|TAR|TIF|TIFF|TTF|TTC|_TTF|WAV|WMA|WRI|WOFF|WOFF2|XLA|XLS|XLSX|XLT|XLW|ZIP)$">
FileETag MTime Size
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Pragma "public"
    Header append Cache-Control "public"
     Header set X-Powered-By "W3 Total Cache/0.9.5"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(bmp|class|doc|docx|eot|exe|ico|json|mdb|mpp|otf|_otf|odb|odc|odf|odg|odp|ods|odt|ogg|pdf|pot|pps|ppt|pptx|svg|svgz|swf|tif|tiff|ttf|ttc|_ttf|wav|wri|woff|woff2|xla|xls|xlsx|xlt|xlw|BMP|CLASS|DOC|DOCX|EOT|EXE|ICO|JSON|MDB|MPP|OTF|_OTF|ODB|ODC|ODF|ODG|ODP|ODS|ODT|OGG|PDF|POT|PPS|PPT|PPTX|SVG|SVGZ|SWF|TIF|TIFF|TTF|TTC|_TTF|WAV|WRI|WOFF|WOFF2|XLA|XLS|XLSX|XLT|XLW)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
     Header unset Last-Modified
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
# END W3TC Browser Cache
# BEGIN W3TC Page Cache core
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_ENC:_gzip]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} w3tc_preview [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_PREVIEW:_preview]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =""
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !(comment_author|wp\-postpass|w3tc_logged_out|wordpress_logged_in|wptouch_switch_toggle) [NC]
RewriteCond "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index%{ENV:W3TC_PREVIEW}.html%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" -f
RewriteRule .* "/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index%{ENV:W3TC_PREVIEW}.html%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" [L]
</IfModule>
# END W3TC Page Cache core
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://mywebsite.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://mywebsite.com$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.mywebsite.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.mywebsite.com$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://mywebsite.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://mywebsite.com$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://www.mywebsite.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://www.mywebsite.com$      [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp)$ https://www.dlapiper.com/~/media/Images/Insights/Publications/2015/warning.jpg [R,NC]
```

Comment: Hotlinking protection is based on the referer sent by the client and can be spoofed. So this protection can be easily bypassed.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois — No, it can't. A website hotlinking images from another site can't control the referer their visitors' browsers send to the other site.

Comment: It can easily be bypassed for anyone that really wants to. Just create a proxy on your site: `imgproxy.php?img=http://path/to/image` and you can send what ever headers you want... sure, it's not _really_ hotlinking then (since it goes through your site first) but close enough and easily automated...

Comment: Anyway, i have asked other... not how to bypass... :)

Comment: Is the `warning.jpg` image hosted on your site, or another domain? If it's on your site, then this should really be an _internal rewrite_, not an _external redirect_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if i put the link of any images hosted on this other website, directly in the address bar, i see the real image.

Well, the code you have posted should be doing the same thing as well. When you type a URL directly into the browsers address bar, the HTTP Referer (part of the HTTP Request headers) is empty - there is no Referer. And that is what the first *condition* checks for:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
```

With the directives you have posted, the `RewriteRule` is only processed (ie. the redirect occurs) when the HTTP Referer is *not* empty.

Also, make sure these directives come before your WordPress directives.

Check the network request headers in the Browser's object inspector. Do you see a `Referer` header?

**UPDATE:**

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://mywebsite.com/.*$      [NC]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://mywebsite.com$      [NC]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.mywebsite.com/.*$      [NC]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.mywebsite.com$      [NC]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://mywebsite.com/.*$      [NC]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://mywebsite.com$      [NC]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://www.mywebsite.com/.*$      [NC]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://www.mywebsite.com$      [NC]
> ```

Incidentally, all of this is the same as the one-liner (which is preferable) from your original code sample:

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?mywebsite.com [NC]
> ```

The code you had originally is preferable.

---

Just to summarise, the following should effectively prevent hotlinking:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpe?g|png|gif|bmp)$ - [NC,F]
```

Your websites domain being `example.com`. This simply returns a 403 Forbidden when an image is hotlinked (not redirected to another image). The first `RewriteCond` directive allows direct requests, when the HTTP Referer is empty.

If you still want your images viewable from (Google) image search, then you will also need to implement additional conditions for each. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !google\. [NC]
```

Comment: mmmm... its a little difficult understand what you have write, i have never do all this till now. I have write directives at the top of the .htaccess, but nothing changes. If you know the exact directives to do it, please, write me here please. The image `warning.jpg` is hosted to another websites found randomly on google

Comment: Make sure you've cleared your browser cache. You should not redirect to someone else's `warning.jpg` - that is very bad practise!? The code you already have should work. Add your entire .htaccess file to your question so we can check.

Comment: Right! i know that i should not redirect to someone else, its only temporary :)
In the cpanel, the icon "hotlinking protection" has helped me writing a similar code trough the wizard, but after other test, i've found the issue! Is in the htaccess but i don't understand WHERE it is.
Now i will edit the answer with the htaccess code.

Comment: if i remove the code between `# BEGIN W3TC Browser Cache` and `# END W3TC Browser Cache` everything works fine! :( But i can't remove...

Comment: "make sure these directives come before your WordPress directives" - before _all_ the other WordPress directives, including the the "W3TC Browser Cache" directives. The hotlink protection should be at the very top of your `.htaccess` file. (You currently have it at the very end.)

Comment: if i write at the begin of `.htaccess` the linked image (warning.jpg) doesn't comes up, the browser doesn't show linked image :( damn! :(

Comment: Isn't that what you are trying to achieve? If you type the image URL directly into the browser's address bar you shouldn't get "warning.jpg", you should see the image you initially requested?

Comment: i mean another thing, i have a local test page where i hotlink images from my main website, just to try, and with directives at begin, i don't see any warning.jpg image... on my test page :(

Comment: Are these pages all HTTPS? There might be an issue if you are trying to redirect from HTTP to HTTPS. However, you shouldn't really be _redirecting_ at all. Effective anti-hotlinking would simply be to drop the request. You should update your question with the actual code you are using - if the directives are really at the top of the file and not at the end. (They won't work at all if they are at the end.) However, the code you had in the beginning should work - so, as you say, the problem may lie somewhere else. Maybe a caching issue?

Comment: Already tell you, the issue was inside `# BEGIN W3TC Browser Cache` and `# END W3TC Browser Cache`, a piece of code generated from plugin W3TC for wordpress. Directives at begin of the file, doesn't show `RewriteRule .*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp)$ https://www.dlapiper.com/~/media/Images/Insights/Publications/2015/warning.jpg [R,NC]` so i put them back near the end.
The issue was fault of this plugin W3TC.
Anyway, i have appreciated lot your help! Thanks! :D